# Query shows half of needed information LINQtoXML C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML document with the list of countries, cities and other geographic objects that looks like:

```
<mondial>
   <continent id="1" name="Europe"/>
   <continent id="2" name="Asia"/>
   <continent id="3" name="America"/>
   <continent id="4" name="Australia/Oceania"/>
   <continent id="5" name="Africa"/>
   <country id="f0_136" name="Albania" capital="f0_1461" population="3249136" datacode="AL" total_area="28750" population_growth="1.34" infant_mortality="49.2" gdp_agri="55" gdp_total="4100" inflation="16" indep_date="28 11 1912" government="emerging democracy" car_code="AL">
     <name>
       Albania
     </name>
     <city id="f0_1461" country="f0_136" longitude="10.7" latitude="46.2">
       <name>
         Tirane
       </name>
       <population year="87">
         192000
       </population>
     </city>
     <city id="f0_36498" country="f0_136" longitude="19.2" latitude="42.2">
       <name>
         Shkoder
       </name>
       <population year="87">
         62000
       </population>
       <located_at type="lake" water="f0_39058"/>
     </city>
     <city id="f0_36504" country="f0_136" longitude="19.3" latitude="41.2">
       <name>
         Durres
       </name>
       <population year="87">
         60000
       </population>
       <located_at type="sea" water="f0_38042"/>
     </city>
//etc it's only small part
```

and task to show all cities with population above 100000 using LINQtoXML
some cities doesn't have any `population` at all.
So I made this:

```
var cities = from c in doc.Descendants("city")
             where c.Element("population") != null 
                   && (int)c.Element("population") > 100000
             select new
             {
                 name = c.Element("name"),
                 population = c.Element("population")
             };
foreach (var c in cities)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", c.name, c.population);
```

but it shows only approximately half of the cities

Comment: `(int)c.Element("population") > 100000` try `(int)c.Element("population").Value > 100000`

Comment: @TimonPost That would not compile as `Value` is a `string` whereas `XElement` has a explicit cast defined for `int`.

Comment: I'm not seeing an obvious issue with your query.  Are you absolutely sure it's skipping cities with a population over 100000?  And if so can you include the xml for at least one of those cities?

Comment: It is difficult to see the problem because the xml is broken and not compleet. Could you provide an xml file with more citys and one that  has also closing tags to close the elements. Have you checked how many elements this `doc.Descendants("city")`  returns? And are you sure that the result is not just corrent?

Comment: I am sure that it shows only half: this xml starts from Albania, Tirane with population > 10000 and I got Swale as a first result. 
File is here: [DropMeFile](http://dropmefiles.com/cV1Q3)

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't that the console doesn't scroll back far enough?  Try putting a `Console.Read()` after the `Console.WriteLine` in the `foreach` to see each one at a time.  Or do `Console.WriteLine(cities.Count())` to see the total.  When I ran your code the console only scrolled to Swale, but it actually does print out Tirane.

Comment: @juharr thank you a lot.
It does prints all!
Thank you again and sorry for stupid question

Comment: Better yet change your `select` to only capture the name and population like `name = c.Element("name").Value.Trim()` and `population = (int)c.Element("population")` so you don't print out the extra xml and newlines.